# Celery sqlalchemy session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

How can I use sqlalchemy models in celery delayed tasks ?

It looks like celery has this option https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/database/session.py , but I can't find an example how to use it.

```
@celery.task
def mytask(data):
   # how to I get session here?
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034098/sqlalchemy-session-handling-in-delayed-celery-tasks) thread didn't helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason to not just create the session as a global variable and use it in the celery tasks?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources
some_engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

# create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

# create a Session
session = Session()

@celery.task
def mytask(data):
  session.commit(data)
```

Comment: timeout ? will session reconnect if it will run for days and weeks ?

Comment: As far as I know, the engine will ask for a connection to the DB on an as needed basis, so whenever a transaction is called. Read up on the engine config section of SQLAlchemy at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#pooling

Comment: @twoface88  , you have the option in the sessionmaker to use the pool recycle option http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle